# Nested RecyclerView onClick not triggered

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, nestedrecyclerview

I have two nested RecyclerViews  - basically a list of horizontal RecyclerViews and I am struggling to make the items in the horizontal RecyclerView clickable.

This is the main layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/overview_list"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <components.emptyView.EmptyView
        android:id="@+id/empty_state"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then RecyclerView has the following item layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/tables"
                                           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                           android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                           android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                           android:clipToPadding="false"
                                           android:paddingEnd="18dp"
                                           android:paddingStart="18dp"/>
```

And I'm trying to get the onclick setup in the adapter for the inner RecyclerView as follows:

```html
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LeagueTableViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Pair<Long, String> table = tables.get(position);
        holder.bindTable(table.first, table.second);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // click event here
            }
        });
    }
```

I've tried making the ViewHolder's itemview as clickable programatically and in XML and it doesn't seem to make a difference. Same for the inner RecyclerView.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Added parent RecyclerView adapter

```js
public class OverviewListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {
    public final static int TEAM_PICTURE = 0;
    public final static int FIXTURES = 1;
    public final static int LEAGUE_TABLES = 2;
    public final static int LATEST_NEWS = 3;
    public final static int LATEST_EVENTS = 4;
    private final RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool;

    private List<BaseOverviewItemVM> viewModels = new ArrayList<>();
    private int tint;

    private OverviewLatestNewsVM newsVM;
    private OverviewLatestEventsVM eventsVM;
    private OverviewTablesVM tablesVM;
    private OverviewFixturesVM fixturesVM;
    private OverviewTeamPicVM teamPicVM;


    OverviewListAdapter(int tint) {
        this.tint = tint;
        viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
    }

    void addViewModel(OverviewLatestNewsVM viewModel){
        if(newsVM == null){
            newsVM = viewModel;
            viewModels.add(newsVM);
            sort();
            int viewModelIndex = viewModels.indexOf(newsVM);
            notifyItemInsertedIfValid(viewModelIndex);
        } else {
            int currentNewsIndex = viewModels.indexOf(newsVM);
            newsVM = viewModel;
            if(currentNewsIndex >= 0) {
                this.viewModels.set(currentNewsIndex, newsVM);
            }
            notifyItemChangedIfValid(currentNewsIndex);
        }
    }

    void addViewModel(OverviewLatestEventsVM viewModel){
        if(eventsVM == null){
            eventsVM = viewModel;
            viewModels.add(eventsVM);
            sort();
            int viewModelIndex = viewModels.indexOf(eventsVM);
            notifyItemChangedIfValid(viewModelIndex);
        } else {
            int currentIndex = viewModels.indexOf(eventsVM);
            eventsVM = viewModel;
            if(currentIndex >= 0) {
                this.viewModels.set(currentIndex, eventsVM);
            }
            notifyItemChangedIfValid(currentIndex);
        }
    }

    void addViewModel(OverviewFixturesVM viewModel){
        if(fixturesVM == null){
            fixturesVM = viewModel;
            viewModels.add(fixturesVM);
            sort();
            int viewModelIndex = viewModels.indexOf(fixturesVM);
            notifyItemChangedIfValid(viewModelIndex);
        } else {
            int currentIndex = viewModels.indexOf(fixturesVM);
            fixturesVM = viewModel;
            if(currentIndex >= 0) {
                this.viewModels.set(currentIndex, fixturesVM);
            }
            notifyItemChangedIfValid(currentIndex);
        }
    }

    void addViewModel(OverviewTablesVM viewModel){
        if(tablesVM == null){
            tablesVM = viewModel;
            viewModels.add(tablesVM);
            sort();
            int viewModelIndex = viewModels.indexOf(tablesVM);
            notifyItemChangedIfValid(viewModelIndex);
        } else {
            int currentIndex = viewModels.indexOf(tablesVM);
            tablesVM = viewModel;
            if(currentIndex >= 0) {
                this.viewModels.set(currentIndex, tablesVM);
            }
            notifyItemChangedIfValid(currentIndex);
        }
    }

    void addViewModel(OverviewTeamPicVM viewModel){
        if(teamPicVM == null){
            teamPicVM = viewModel;
            viewModels.add(teamPicVM);
            sort();
            int viewModelIndex = viewModels.indexOf(teamPicVM);
            notifyItemChangedIfValid(viewModelIndex);
        } else {
            int currentIndex = viewModels.indexOf(teamPicVM);
            teamPicVM = viewModel;
            if(currentIndex >= 0) {
                this.viewModels.set(currentIndex, teamPicVM);
            }
            notifyItemChangedIfValid(currentIndex);
        }
    }

    private void sort(){
        // sort by the item type defined at the top of this class
        Collections.sort(viewModels, (o1, o2) -> {
            if(o1.getType() > o2.getType()){
                return 1;
            } else if(o1.getType() < o2.getType()){
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
    }

    private void notifyItemInsertedIfValid(int index){
        if(index >= 0 && index < getItemCount()){
            notifyItemInserted(index);
        } else {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void notifyItemChangedIfValid(int index){
        if(index >= 0 && index < getItemCount()){
            notifyItemChanged(index);
        } else {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch (viewType){
            case FIXTURES:
                View fixturesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_overview_fixtures, parent, false);
                OverviewFixturesVH fixturesHolder = new OverviewFixturesVH(fixturesView);
                fixturesHolder.fixturesOverview.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
                return fixturesHolder;
            case LEAGUE_TABLES:
                View tablesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_overview_league_tables, parent, false);
                OverviewTablesVH tablesHolder = new OverviewTablesVH(tablesView);
                tablesHolder.tablesList.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
                return tablesHolder;
            case LATEST_EVENTS:
                View upcomingEvents = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_latest_list_view, parent, false);
                return new OverviewLatestEventsVH(upcomingEvents, tint);
            case TEAM_PICTURE:
                View teamPicView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_overview_team_pic, parent, false);
                return new OverviewTeamPicVH(teamPicView);
            default:
                View latestNewsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_latest_list_view, parent, false);
                return new OverviewLatestNewsVH(latestNewsView, tint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder instanceof  OverviewFixturesVH) {
            Optional<BaseOverviewItemVM> fixturesVM = getViewModelOfType(FIXTURES);
            fixturesVM.ifPresent(viewModel -> ((OverviewFixturesVH) holder).setFixtures(((OverviewFixturesVM)viewModel).getFixtures()));
        } else if (holder instanceof OverviewTablesVH) {
            Optional<BaseOverviewItemVM> tablesVM = getViewModelOfType(LEAGUE_TABLES);
            tablesVM.ifPresent(vm -> ((OverviewTablesVH) holder).setTableIds(((OverviewTablesVM) vm).getTableIds()));
        } else if (holder instanceof OverviewLatestEventsVH){
            Optional<BaseOverviewItemVM> eventsVM = getViewModelOfType(LATEST_EVENTS);
            eventsVM.ifPresent(vm -> ((OverviewLatestEventsVH) holder).setEvents(((OverviewLatestEventsVM) vm).getEvents()));
        } else if (holder instanceof OverviewLatestNewsVH){
            Optional<BaseOverviewItemVM> newsVM = getViewModelOfType(LATEST_NEWS);
            newsVM.ifPresent(vm -> ((OverviewLatestNewsVH) holder).setNews(((OverviewLatestNewsVM) vm).getNews()));
        } else if (holder instanceof OverviewTeamPicVH){
            Optional<BaseOverviewItemVM> teamPicVM = getViewModelOfType(TEAM_PICTURE);
            teamPicVM.ifPresent(vm -> ((OverviewTeamPicVH) holder).setPictureUrl(((OverviewTeamPicVM) vm).getTeamPicUrl()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return viewModels.get(position).getType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return viewModels.size();
    }

    private Optional<BaseOverviewItemVM> getViewModelOfType(int type){
        if(viewModels != null ) {
            for (BaseOverviewItemVM viewModel : viewModels) {
                if(viewModel.getType() == type){
                    return Optional.of(viewModel);
                }
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: try putting your main layout inside nested scrollview

Comment: Can you include your parent recyclerview's adapter code?

Comment: Using a NestedScrollView didn't work :(

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf added it, thanks

Comment: @TudorS. check [this](https://github.com/malikmotani/NestedRecyclerView-Master)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to handle it creating a listener and handle the call with it:

```
public interface clickListenerItem {
        void onItemClick(Item element);
    }
```

add this interface in your `adapter` and in your `main`.

Adding this function to your `*nameclass*ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder` :

```
 public void bind(final ItemName item, final clickListenerItem listener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }
```

then add to your Adapter variables: `private final clickListenerItem clickItem;`

in your constructor: `this.clickItem = clickItem;`

and in `onBindViewHolder` of your adapter call:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final @NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.bind(list.get(position), clickItem);
}
```

now when initiliazing your adapter in the main you just add your listener adding it with a call like this:

```
adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, list, (new ItemAdapter.clickListenerItem(){
            @Override public void onItemClick(Item thisItem) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading Item...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent viewElem = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewItem.class);
                startActivityForResult(viewElem ,codeForResult);
  }
        }));
```

I hope this will help you, obviusly you can change the last part for not calling a new activity but changing it with what you want to see or do with your item.